# Doctrine - migration filed change

Tags: symfony, doctrine, database-migration

I have generated my table within Symfony project and generated migration that was executed.

That table is now full of data and meanwhile I had to change type of two fields in it form *string* to *text*.

I have ran `php bin/console doctrine:migrations:diff`  and generated new migration file that has those two changes.

As doctrine won't let me execute that new migration when table has data in it, is there a way I can write code within that migration that will pick up all the old data, perform the migration, and then enter the new transformed data into the database?

My migration file:

```
final class Version20210901140835 extends AbstractMigration
{
 public function getDescription() : string
 {
    return '';
}

public function up(Schema $schema) : void
{
    // this up() migration is auto-generated, please modify it to your needs
    $this->abortIf($this->connection->getDatabasePlatform()->getName() !== 'mysql', 'Migration can only be executed safely on \'mysql\'.');

    $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE logs CHANGE old_value old_value LONGTEXT DEFAULT NULL, CHANGE new_value new_value LONGTEXT DEFAULT NULL');
}

public function down(Schema $schema) : void
{
    // this down() migration is auto-generated, please modify it to your needs
    $this->abortIf($this->connection->getDatabasePlatform()->getName() !== 'mysql', 'Migration can only be executed safely on \'mysql\'.');

    $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE logs CHANGE old_value old_value VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci, CHANGE new_value new_value VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci');
  }
}
```

Comment: *As doctrine won't let me execute that new migration when table has data in it*. How did you come to that conclusion? What command are you using to deploy the migration? The point of using migrations is to be able to rollout changes like you have to your database overtime. You can add any query you would like to your migration files manually. Including `CREATE temp_logs SELECT * FROM logs`.  Though find it odd that your up and down tables changed from `logs` to `alogs`

Comment: Create a new field in your table, and copy all existing data to this field, and then delete the old one and rename your field.